# Check if element(s) count>0 in Selenium using Linq in C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I have id's like follows:

```
id='vat-code-A'

id='vat-code-B'

id='vat-code-c'

id='vat-code-D'
```

I want to check if the above `element(s) count>0`, which can be done using a for each loop. But, is there a way to perform the above requirement with Linq as below.

```
 var codes = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
 var vatElement = Driver.FindElements(By.Id($'vat-code-{codes .Select(x=>x)}"));                    
        if (((vatCodeElement.Count()) > 0) == true)
        {                
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Please show us your existing working code.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nZkoi5 ... `By.Id("id='vat-code-System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator``2[System.String,System.String]")` doesn't make much sens

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
var codes = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
var elements = codes.Select(c => driver.FindElements(By.Id("vat-code-" + c))).ToList();
if (elements.Select(x=>x.Count).Sum()>0)
 {
      // return true    
 }
```

or you can use *SelectMany* :

```
var elementsCount = elements.SelectMany(x => x).Count();
if (elementsCount > 0)
{
   // return true             
}
```

if you want to all elements be present you can use :

```
var codes = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
var elements = codes.Select(c => driver.FindElements(By.Id("vat-code-" + c))).ToList();
if (elements.Where(x => x.Count > 0).Count()==4)
 {
      // return true    
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Mehrdad. Correct me if I am wrong! If one of the elements is missing, this will still pass, I think. I should have asked my question with clarity. If I change the above code to                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                     
 if (elements.Select(x=>x.Count).Sum()>4)
 {
      // return true    
 }   Will it confirm the presence of all the four elements?

Comment: "If one of the elements is missing, this will still pass?"  Yes

Comment: you want to all elements be present?

Comment: Yes. I should have mentioned it. Sorry